# I can't run Steam on my Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam

I have a problem with Steam on my Ubuntu 15.04 machine, when I want to run Steam I got this message from terminal

```
    steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Has it worked on 14.04 for you before? Or are you new to Ubuntu?

Most steam issues related to the client itself stem from the fact that the client is 32-bit for your OS is 64bit which has some issues on linux-based distros. I solved this issue myself with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` which removed my error message - which, granted, wasn't the same as yours, but it might work.

Perhaps elaborate on your graphics driver. Can you provide the output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2`?

Comment: I'm newbie in using Ubuntu. And i can't install ia32-libs. Also the "lspci -k | grep VGA -A2" result are: 07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 841a
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau

Comment: Use ` brackets for entering input and output. Can you provide the error you get from trying to `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`? Which game do you plan on playing on Steam on linux? Not all work properly, but at least you have a Nvidia gpu.

Comment: I get 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
'